# UICollectionView doesn't show cell images

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I have a `viewcontroller` and `uicollectionview` in it.

I used following code, but there is no visible images in `uicollectionview`, just yellow boxes :

**myviewcontroller.h**

```
{
IBOutlet UICollectionView *gallery1;
//IBOutlet UIImage *inimage;
NSArray *recipePhotos;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UICollectionView *gallery1;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImage *inimage;
```

**and myviewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

recipePhotos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"im1.png","im2.png", "im3.png", "im4.png", "im5.png", "im6.png",  nil];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[self.gallery1 setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[self.gallery1 setAllowsSelection:YES];
self.gallery1.delegate=self;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection: (NSInteger)section {
return recipePhotos.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}

// cellforitematindexpath

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[gallery1 registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%d",indexPath.row]];
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [gallery1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%d",indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell addSubview:recipeImageView];
return cell;
}
```

I cannot see any image (image file are existing) in cells in uicollectionview.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did this resolve for you, Murat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Adam is right, don't call `registerClass` every time you make a new cell.  However...

Something is wrong here:

```
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell addSubview:recipeImageView];
```

You are [asking the cell for a subview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag%3a), then setting an image for that subview, and then attempting to add that subview back into the hierarchy...where it already is?

Does that subview even exist?  When is it created?  Perhaps you should subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and create the subview in its `viewDidLoad` function?  Maybe like this:

```
UIImageView *recipeImageView = [UIImageView alloc] init];
recipeImageView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
[self.contentView addSubview:recipeImageView];
recipeImageView.tag = 100;
```

Then in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` you do this:

```
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

You don't have to add it back into the hierarchy; it's already there.

Edit:

Oh, Adam is also right about adding the imageView to the contentView rather than simply as a subview; I edited my code to reflect this.

Comment: You're right, that UIImageView isn't going to be valid - must be created as you show.

Comment: @AdamEberbach And you are right, custom content goes in the `contentView`, as per http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewCell/contentView  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

here is my take:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imgView.image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:imgView];
    return cell;
}
```

The imageView should have a frame... the best option is to create your own frame.
also make sure that the images will fit the frame ratio and clip to the bounds!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing

```
[gallery1 registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%d",indexPath.row]];
```

in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` - you should register the class once and then dequeue cells according to the registration.

Do you have the images in your project? If you don't, `imageNamed`: won't find them. Check to see if the image has been loaded or is `nil`.

Finally, try adding the `recipeImageView` to the cell's `contentView` rather than as a subview (of the main view).

Comment: Thanks for answer Adam, yes I have already images in project folder but I could not understand for [gallery1 registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%d",indexPath.row]]; usage and registering just once. I am not sure if I have to move the line in to viewLoad? And one thing more: self.contentView is not found, I did not declare/use before.

Comment: viewDidLoad is often the place to use registerClass, yes. You should use cell.contentView (not self.contentView).

Answer (score 0):

be careful:

doing:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView **alloc**] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imgView.image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell **addSubview:imgView**];
    return cell;
}
```

You are allocating an image (and it can be ok.. even if a bit expensive..) BUT ADDING every time, so using a cell 100 times will add 100 subviews.